# Remove an object from an array in Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to remove an object from an array in a document using mongoose.

This is an example of an entry:

```
{
  _id: "12345",
  folder: {
    name: "Folder1",
    files: [
      {
        fileName: "File 1",
        fileID: "6789",
        folderID: "12345"
      }
    ],
    active: true
  }
}
```

This is what I am currently doing to remove the file from the array. The `Attachment.unlink` is what removes the file from the gridfs filestore. That part of the code works. My object however will not remove from the array.

```
router.delete("/filesystem/:id", (req, res, next) => {
  Attachment.unlink(req.params.id, (error, attachment) => {
    if (!attachment) return res.status(404);
    if (error) return next(error);
    Folder.findByIdAndUpdate(
      {
        _id: req.body.folderID
      },
      {
        $pull: {
          "folder.files": {
            $elemMatch: { fileID: req.params.id }
          }
        }
      },
      { multi: true, safe: true },
      (error, folder) => {
        if (error) return next(error);
        return res.status(200).json({
          folder
        });
      }
    );
  });
});
```

I have also tried to use `update` rather than `findByIdAndUpdate`. **How do I remove an object from the array where the `fileID` is `6789`?**

Comment: Have also tried casting type objectID ```mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.id)```

Comment: Do your subdocuments have `_id`s? If so you could do `folder.files.id(fileId).remove()`. See https://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html#removing-subdocs

Comment: They do not have `_id`s it is all one schema

Comment: Have you tried `$pull: { "folder.files":  { fileID: req.params.id } }` instead of $elemMatch?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `array.pull` (see https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#mongoosearray_MongooseArray-pull)

Below is a sample where I've modified your code and used async/await instead of callbacks.

```
router.delete("/filesystem/:id", (req, res, next) => {
  Attachment.unlink(req.params.id, async (error, attachment) => {
    if (!attachment) return res.status(404);
    if (error) return next(error);

    try {
      const folder = await Folder.findById(req.body.folderID);
      folder.folder.files.pull({ fileID: req.params.id });
      await folder.save();

      return res.status(200).json({
        folder
      });
    } catch (error) {
      return next(error);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: This gets the value of the whole array

Comment: Are you certain? Pull should remove it from the object. Obviously you have to complete the save as per my example, otherwise the change won't be saved to the database.

Comment: I just realized that your Folder model has a "folder" field, so it's `folder.folder.files.pull` and not `folder.files.pull`.

Comment: Yes I recognized that and tried it the correct way. I believe the pull may not be working because it is not another Schema or an ObjectID like the docs state

Comment: I dunno, I have a feeling that something else is wrong since neither array.pull or findByIdAndUpdate is working for you. Can you find the object in the array if you use for example `const file = folder.folder.files.find(file => file.fileID === req.params.id)` in my code sample? Are you sure the field name is fileID? Are you sure the value isn't wrong (i.e. req.params.id is a Number but fileID expects a String